# Quick Sort significantly slower

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

I am working on my lab assignment which is all about sorting algorithms, `Heap Sort`, `Merge Sort`, and `Quick Sort`. I finished the assigment pretty much, but after taking time measurements for each algorithm I got suprising results.

```
[***** [Merge Sort] *****]

[Original]: [54599, 62697, 92032, 19179, 17296, 27068, 99563, 9829, 89929, 57140]
[Sorted]:   [9829, 17296, 19179, 27068, 54599, 57140, 62697, 89929, 92032, 99563]


[size]:  10     [time]: 2      [ms]
[size]:  100    [time]: 15     [ms]
[size]:  1000   [time]: 170    [ms]
[size]:  10000  [time]: 2122   [ms]
[size]:  100000 [time]: 22946  [ms]

[***** [Quick Sort] *****]

[Original]: [10017, 37607, 51285, 83517, 7500, 81469, 40379, 19721, 48524, 74062]
[Sorted]:   [7500, 10017, 19721, 37607, 40379, 48524, 51285, 74062, 81469, 83517]


[size]:  10     [time]: 24     [ms]
[size]:  100    [time]: 95     [ms]
[size]:  1000   [time]: 1001   [ms]
[size]:  10000  [time]: 9697   [ms]
[size]:  100000 [time]: 107627 [ms]

[***** [Heap Sort] *****]

[Original]: [62697, 92032, 19179, 17296, 27068, 99563, 9829, 89929, 57140, 33429]
[Sorted]:   [9829, 17296, 19179, 27068, 33429, 57140, 62697, 89929, 92032, 99563]


[size]:  10     [time]: 1      [ms]
[size]:  100    [time]: 14     [ms]
[size]:  1000   [time]: 239    [ms]
[size]:  10000  [time]: 3088   [ms]
[size]:  100000 [time]: 39615  [ms]
```

I know that all of these algorithms are supposed to run in `O(nlogn)` and are considered the "fastest" sorting algorithms out there, but the time measurements for `Quick Sort` are very different from `Heap Sort` and `Merge Sort`.

I am using a random pivot, since I read that `QS` is very in-efficient if all of the elements are sorted or if all of them are the same.

Here is my code for QS:

```
/**
 * @brief Generates a random pivot index between low and high (inclusive)
 * @param low Starting index of the array
 * @param high Ending index of the array
 * @return Random pivot index
 */
int random_pivot(int low, int high) {
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(nullptr)));
    return low + rand() % (high - low + 1);
}

/**
 * @brief Partitions the array and returns the partition index
 * @param arr The array to be partitioned
 * @param low Starting index of the partition
 * @param high Ending index of the partition
 * @return Partition index
 */
int partition(int* arr, int low, int high) {
    int pivotIndex = random_pivot(low, high);
    int pivot = arr[pivotIndex];
    std::swap(arr[pivotIndex], arr[high]);

    int i = low - 1; // Index of the smaller element

    for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++) {
        // If current element is smaller than or equal to the pivot
        if (arr[j] <= pivot) {
            i++; // Increment index of smaller element
            std::swap(arr[i], arr[j]); // Swap current element with the smaller element
        }
    }

    std::swap(arr[i + 1], arr[high]); // Swap the pivot with the element at the partition index
    return i + 1; // Return the partition index
}

/**
 * @brief Sorts an array using the QuickSort algorithm
 * @param arr The array to be sorted
 * @param low Starting index of the array
 * @param high Ending index of the array
 */
void quick_sort_helper(int* arr, int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        int partition_index = partition(arr, low, high); // partition the array and get the partition index
        quick_sort_helper(arr, low, partition_index - 1); // recursively sort the left subarray
        quick_sort_helper(arr, partition_index + 1, high); // recursively sort the right subarray
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Sorts an array using the QuickSort algorithm
 * @param arr The array to be sorted
 * @param size The size of the array
 */
void quick_sort(int* arr, int size) {
    quick_sort_helper(arr, 0, size - 1);
}
```

Code block for taking time measurements:

```
/**
 * @brief Measures the execution time of a sorting algorithm on arrays of different sizes.
 * @param sorting_function The sorting function to be measured.
 */
void measure_sort(void (*sorting_function)(int*, int)) {
  int sizes[] = {10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000}; // sizes of the array
  int const MAX = 100000;
  int const SMALL = 10;

  for (auto i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      int* arr = new int[sizes[i]];
      for(auto j = 0; j < sizes[i]; j++) { //fill array with random numbers
        arr[j] = rand() % MAX;
      }

      if (sizes[i] == SMALL) { //print og array before sorting
        std::cout << "\n[Original]: "; // << std::setw(2);
        print_arr(arr, sizes[i]);
      }

      // Measure execution time
      auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      sorting_function(arr, sizes[i]);
      auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count();

      if(sizes[i] == SMALL) {
        std::string const SPACE = "   "; //width const to align output
        std::cout << std::setw(4) << "[Sorted]:" << SPACE;
        print_arr(arr, sizes[i]);
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
      }

      int const SIZE_W = 9;
      int const TIME_W = 8;
      int const W = 6;
      std::cout << std::left << std::setw(SIZE_W) << "[size]: " << std::setw(W+1) << sizes[i] << std::left <<std::setw(TIME_W) << "[time]: " << std::setw(W) << duration << " [ms]" << std::endl;

      // Clean up dynamically allocated memory
      delete[] arr;
  }
}
```

Could someone explain to me why `QS` is taking a lot more time to sort a random array than the other algorithms?

I reviewed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787964/c-quick-sort-algorithm) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59237081/big-o-question-for-quicksort-with-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573408/why-is-my-quick-sort-so-slow) but I still don't understand what's going on.

Comment: The code provided is incomplete, and will not compile.  A [mcve] would be most helpful.  Have you tried to step through the code with a debugger?  What compiler switches are you using?  Is your data sorted, or are the elements the same — if not, the random pivot is not helpful.

Comment: Single measurement is hard to argue about. Normally you want to do several measurements and find average time. This being said, I have strong suspicion about `random_pivot`. Not only calling `time()` might be expensive (since it requires a system call), but you also reset random engine every call, which means your random numbers are likely far from random.

Comment: O(n) or O(n log(n)) only say something about the limit for very large datasets (they discard constant overhead time), so your dataset must be big enough (yours are still very very small). Also you should measure on a release build with optimizations enabled and like any scientific experiment you should repeat it multiple times (on a system you have control over, eg, virus scanner kicks in... measurement unreliable)

Comment: Further observations, in current C++ don't use "C" style arrays (or pointers pretending to be an array), use [std::span](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) to model partial (views on)  arrays. And replace function pointers with [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). It kind of looks like your datastructures teacher hasn't been updating his C++ knowledge ever since C++11 was released.

Comment: Also, shouldn't you be using the same set of random values for all 3 sorts?

Comment: @PepijnKramer `-std=c++11` is a necessary compilation flag

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I thought so too, since that allows for some "control" over the time measurements but apparently, that's the way she wants us to do it. I am just following instructions

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I made a plot using `matplotlib` and I included 21 measurements, the graph I am seeing is way above the `QS` and `MS` graph

Comment: @Dude -- Well, I took your code, used [these examples of sorting algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c), and wrote [this program](https://godbolt.org/z/9bf98aeW9)., using `#include <random>` functions to generate random numbers instead of `rand()`.  Compare the results with yours.

Comment: You don’t want to call `srand` for every random number—the whole point of a PRNG is to seed it **once** and get a random *sequence*.  You might even get 0s repeatedly during the same second (the resolution of `time`).

Comment: @PepijnKramer: `std::function` is good for storing one of several function _objects_, especially lambdas with captures.  Using function pointers here is quite appropriate, although in similar cases with more than one call per pointer you might want them to be template parameters for efficiency.

Comment: @DavisHerring you are right they are fine here. I just find that allowing for lambdas (with captures) gives a lot more freedom in the use of an api.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Wow, thanks a lot. I'll run it and compare it to my results. I, unfortunately, can't use that since due to "learning" purposes use of the STL is discouraged, the same goes for templates. I do appreciate the work and I think it will be a good way to see if my algorithm is inefficient

Comment: @Dude Instead of `random_pivot`, replace it with what the quicksort function is doing in the link I posted (it is doing a 3-way partition).  If your results (assuming you are running an optimized build) do not get better, then there is something wrong with your quicksort implementation in general.

Comment: If you are not timing your code built with compiler optimizations enabled, be sure to do that. Testing performance of debug builds is rather pointless.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I don't fully understand what you mean by that. I am new to this "field" and all I understand from your comment is "use -O3 and not -g" when compiling and not to run it in a debug environment right?

Comment: @TheCompile-TimeComedian using `-g` is fine - both in debug and release builds; it just adds debug symbols, that doesn't slow down your executable, just takes a bit more disk space. The important bit is to enable the optimizer - that would be `-O1`, `-O2` or `-O3` rather than the default that is `-O0` (no optimization). Read this: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `srand` and `time` for every random pivot is almost certainly impacting the performance of your `quick_sort` implementation. Those calls are expensive relative to the other operations you are performing.

You are correct that a poor choice of pivot can be disastrous for sorted data. However, instead of a random pivot I would suggest the [median of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) strategy for selecting the pivot (also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7560859/1202808)).

The median of three selects the pivot as the median of the first, middle and last element of the partition. This works flawlessly with sorted data and even improves performance on random data by more evenly partitioning the data on average.

**Update**

You may also want to look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76124368/1202808) to another sort related question. The associated code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/cpp-core/sort).

Comment: Not to mention that `srand`/`rand` has a horrible period and small range and `time(0)` is a terrible seed for a (P)RNG, given that it will be the same for any program invoked within the same second and is highly guessable by outside attackers.